# Is there a reusable TFS query picker for Windows applications?

Tags: winforms, tfs

Given a WinForms application, a user needs to select a TFS query.

I know how to get the list of queries through the API and that I could create a treeview-based form from scratch.

The TFS-Addin for Excel has a form to select a query:

[image]

The TeamProjectPicker can be reused in custom .NET applications, I am curious if something similar exists for the Query picker.

Version info:

- TFS 2017 Update 1
- WinForms application with .NET 4.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [TeamProjectPicker Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff733628(v%3Dvs.120)), so we can use the TeamProjectPicker directly.

But cannot find any QueryPicker related classes from [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb141829(v%3Dvs.120)).

So, seems it's not reusable, you may have to get the list of queries through the API.

See [WorkItemStore.Query Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb143578(v=vs.120)) for details.

You can reference below samples:

- [Working With Queries](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/11/17/tfs-api-part-30-working-with-queries/)
- [App-TFSPicker](https://github.com/countersoft/App-TFSPicker/blob/master/TfsPicker.cs)